# Socket.IO - Redis: SUBSCRIBE can't be processed. The connection is already closed

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I have a simple `Redis - Socket.IO` chat application which throws the following (redis)exception when a user hits F5 or tries to refresh the page:

> SUBSCRIBE can't be processed. The connection is already closed.

When a user refreshes the page, the socket reconnects, and my sub `RedisClient` object throws this exception. This event on its turn causes my server.js to crash too. When commenting out all my sub and pub objects in the `io.sockets.on` connection, the socket reconnects without any exception, and the server.js keeps on running.

My server.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var redis = require('redis');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);

var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {

    sub.subscribe("chatbox");

    sub.on("message", function (channel, message) {
        console.log("Message received, publishing...");
        client.send(message);
    });

    client.on("message", function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        pub.publish("chatbox", msg.message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function () {
        sub.quit();
        pub.publish("chatbox", "User: " + client.id + "  is disconnected");
    });

    client.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error " + err);
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

The (simplified) html part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var username ='Someone';
        var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:8888');           
        var msg = {type:'setUsername',user:username};

        socket.json.send(msg);

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log("Connected: " + Date());
        });

        $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
            socket.close();
        })

        //...
```

The node.js stacktrace:

```
AbortError
at handle_offline_command (c:\xampp\htdocs\chatbox\node_modules\redis\index.js:839:15)
at RedisClient.internal_send_command (c:\xampp\htdocs\chatbox\node_modules\redis\index.js:873:9)
at RedisClient.subscribe (c:\xampp\htdocs\chatbox\node_modules\redis\lib\individualCommands.js:419:17)
at Namespace.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\htdocs\chatbox\nodeServer4.js:17:6)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Namespace.emit (c:\xampp\htdocs\chatbox\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:209:10)
at c:\xampp\htdocs\chatbox\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:177:14
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

It seems that the RedisClient objects cannot handle these socket disconnects. Adding a try catch around any of the sub, pub objects (like i.e. `try { sub.subscribe("chatbox"); } catch { }`) did not help either.

**EDIT:**

Adding the following lines keeps the server.js alive, but the exception is still thrown, not being able to subscribe, and hence not to publish:

```
sub.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

pub.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

Error AbortError: SUBSCRIBE can't be processed. The connection is already closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

sub.subscribe("chatbox") should be outside the scope of the io connection. Only one subscribe is required.

```
var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();
sub.subscribe("chatbox");

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
  sub.on("message", function (channel, message) {
  ...
```